# javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: the server presented no authentication mechanisms in Wildfly 10.1

Tags: wildfly, ejb-3.0, openshift-origin, openshift-3, jboss-cli

I am new to EJBs, and I am trying to perform remote invocations on stateless and stateful beans that I have deployed on a pod in my project that is based on Wildfly 10.1 in the new OpenShift 3 (Origin). The code that I am using for initializing the client context looks like:

```
Properties clientProperties = new Properties();  
clientProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
clientProperties.put("remote.connections", "default");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.host", "localhost");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "****");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "****"); clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
EJBClientContext.setSelector(new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(new 
PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(clientProperties)));

Properties contextProperties = new Properties();
contextProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
contextProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "****"); //username
contextProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "****"); //password
Context context = new InitialContext(contextProperties);
String appName = "CloudEAR";
String moduleName = "CloudEjb";
String distinctName = "";
String beanName = "Calculator";
String qualifiedRemoteView = "cloudEJB.view.CalculatorRemote";
String lookupString = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + qualifiedRemoteView;

Calculator calculator = (CalculatorRemote) context.lookup(lookupString);
int sum = calculator.sum(10, 10);
```

And the error message that I get is:

```
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to localhost:8080
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: the server presented no authentication mechanisms
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:378)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:240)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:198)
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:112)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$DelegatingChannelListener.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:1092)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:272)
at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:388)
```

Initially I tried using the "jboss-ejb-client.properties" file, but that wasn't even able to make the remote connection. Now I am manually creating and configuring the EJBClientContext, and at least is successfully connecting to the remote server, but the invocation filas because of authentication failures.

I remember that we used to solve this issue by removing the "security realm" argument in "standalone.xml" files in older versions of OpenShift; however I am not able to find that file in the new version anymore. I have been looking at concepts such as secrets, volumes etc. but I really don't have a clear understanding how this works. When I create a new secret and try to associate it with my pod, the new deployment procedure fails. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you registered in your Wildfly10.1 an user with this username and password? (the value for Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL and Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS)

Comment: I am using the Openshift Origin platform, and using its web console I have added the corresponding user to my container, but I am not sure if that is enough, because I am still getting that error. I am not sure if adding a security context to the pod (application) will solve the problem.